# UBUNTU problem with 'Search your computer and online sources' icon

Tags: 14.04

I am a complete and utter novice with UBUNTU and have just downloaded and installed 14.04 LTS on my Sony Vaio VGN-F415M Laptop.

It has

Intel Pentium M Processor at 1.73Ghz (Yes its an old one)
2 Gb Memory
I've used the 32 Bit download
It has 80 Gb HDD
Nvidia Graphics (not sure which one)

Everything seems to work fine until I select the Icon in the sidebar to access'Search your computer and online sources.

At this point the screen goes haywire (flashing loads of different colours and patterns) and everything locks up. I then have to turn off the laptop and turn it on again to reboot.

How do I fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

- Install *Unity Tweak Tool*
- Start *Unity Tweak Tool*
- Go to 'Unity' -> 'Search'

  - Background blur: "Off"
  - Check Only 'Show "Recently Used" applications'
- Close *Unity Tweak Tool*

It solves the problem a little ...